# Trouble Dockerizing default Shopify starter app

Tags: docker, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I used the Shopify CLI to create a default starter app as described in their [documentation](https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create), by running this command:

```
npm init @shopify/app@latest
```

The app runs fine locally, but after creating a Docker image and running it there, I get the following error:

```
file:///app/index.js:29
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at file:///app/index.js:29:30
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)
Node.js v18.12.1
```

I read that this error is due to a missing env file (either process.env or .env depending on where you look). Why this required file is not automatically created by the Shopify CLI is a mystery to me, as is why the app runs locally without this file.

Nevertheless, I created an env file using the command `npm run shopify app env pull` as described [here](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli/commands#env). I then copied that file to process.env just to be sure. But I still get the TypeError when running in Docker.

I then read [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-node/issues/437) that you should place the env file in the /web folder instead of the root folder. That didn't work either.

My Dockerfile was automatically created by the Shopify CLI, and looks like this:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
ARG SHOPIFY_API_KEY
ENV SHOPIFY_API_KEY=$SHOPIFY_API_KEY
EXPOSE 8081
WORKDIR /app
COPY web .
RUN npm install
RUN cd frontend && npm install && npm run build
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

My .env and process.env files look like this:

```
SHOPIFY_API_KEY=00000000000000000000000000000000
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET=00000000000000000000000000000000
SCOPES=write_products
HOST=https://a1b1-123-456-789-00.eu.ngrok.io
```

What am I missing?

Comment: the .env file is just a way to create environment variables. Try to add a line `ENV SCOPE=write_products` in your docker file where the other `ENV` lines are.

Comment: Thanks @FabioFilippi! Adding ENV SCOPES and HOST values to the Dockerfile worked to get me past those errors. Now I get this error:

`/app/node_modules/@shopify/shopify-api/dist/context.js:37`

`        if (!params.API_SECRET_KEY.length) {`

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

So I tried adding `ARG API_SECRET_KEY=<my_key>` but I still get the error. Is there another way to pass parameters?